# How to run a macro in a specific Sheet, but control the start based on a Value maintained from another Excel File/Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

**Hi,**

How to run a macro in the background in a specific Sheet, and only work with and control the trigger of the Macro based on a calculated Value maintained in another Excel File/Sheet?
The use case is that I want to run a Macro named “TargetCalc” – which trigger either Marcro_01 or Marcro_02 in a specific Sheet depending if Cell C3 in that Sheet has the value 1 or 2.

The Macro example below works nice if everything is maintained or calculated within the active Excel Sheet itself. But - if I instead want to control the value in Cell C3 from a completely another Excel File I have open (where my focus is), then I get the error message “Run-time error ’9 ’: Subscription out of range”

**The Test setup:**

1. Save an Excel File named “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” and rename “Sheet1” to “DisplaySheet1”
2. Copy the VBA Code seen below
3. In the File “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” - in Cell C3, enter: =IF(D3<100,1,2)
4. In the File “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” - in Cell D3, enter the value 105

Result:

a) Cell C3 will display 2 because Cell D3 is 105, which is more than 100 => Macro_01 is triggered

b) If you manually update Cell D3 from 105 to 78 => Macro_02 is triggered
So far so good – and this example works nice.

5. Open a 2nd Excel on the same machine – and rename “Sheet1” to “CalcSheet” and Save this Excel File with the name “CalcFromExcelFile.xlsm”
6. In the File “CalcExcelFile.xlsm” - in Cell A2, enter the value 130
7. Next: Have both Excel Files opened on the same machine – and Go back to the first Excel File “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” Cell D3 and change Cell D3 from a value (105 or 78…) to instead a formula that refers to the other Cell A2 in the other opened Excel File: =[CalcFromExcelFile.xlsm]CalcSheet!$A$2

Result:

a) As long as the “focus” is within Sheet named “DisplaySheet1” in the first “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” – the functionality works as expected when updating the Cell D3 with different numbers.

b) BUT: If you instead have “focus” in the second Excel File “CalcExcelFile.xlsm” and update the Cell A2 in the second Excel File to the Value 97 – Then the macros in the Sheet “DisplaySheet1” in the first “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” does not work.

The popup VBA error says:
Run-time error ’9 ’: Subscription out of range

And when I “Debug” – it points to the row for the Macro_01:
“Worksheets("DisplaySheet").Range("A3").Select”

In addition:

- The workflow I’m after is to have both Excel Files opened on the same machine – where the First Excel File “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” is for Display Purpose and running the Macros – but all manual updates (the focus) is on the second Excel File “CalcFromExcelFile.xlsm”.
- The Sheet will always be named “DisplaySheet1” in the first “DisplayExcelFile.xlsm” – so there is no need to modify the code so that it will work in case I rename the Sheet. My hope is that when I get this use case working, I will then create a 2nd and 3rd Sheet (“DisplaySheet2” and “DisplaySheet2”  within the same First Excel File – so that I can replicate the same thing for these Sheets as well.
- When I tried to get the VBA code working - I tried to make a direct reference to the Sheet name – and I also tried to improve the usage of “Select”, but I got stuck.

The Code

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit

Public TargetValue As Variant
Private Const cTarget As String = "C3"

Sub TargetCalc(ws As Worksheet)
'
If ws.Range(cTarget) <> TargetValue Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case ws.Range(cTarget).Value
        Case 1
            Macro_01
        Case 2
            Macro_02
    End Select
    TargetValue = ws.Range(cTarget).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub

Sub Macro_01()
'
    Worksheets("DisplaySheet").Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Hi_01"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "There_01"
End Sub

Sub Macro_02()
'
    Worksheets("DisplaySheet").Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Hi_02"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "There_02"
End Sub
```

**Sheet1 (DisplaySheet)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    TargetCalc Me
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook**

...empty...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select anything, [almost] ever. If you tell VBA the address, VBA will find it. Therefore you need to sort through your workbooks and worksheets with great care. I usually do this *before* I start programming. That's why you find the definitions at the top of my code below.

Don't worry about the sheet names. The first tab on the left is always `Worksheets(1)`. You can address it by its index number. I think you will probably stick with names like "DisplaySheet1" in the display book but use the index in the calculation workbook. Point is: identify workbooks and worksheets precisely. Note that a worksheet, once defined with a `Set` statement, knows the workbook to which it belongs and you can retrieve that book's name with `Ws.Workbook.Name'.

Note that `ThisWorkbook` identifies the workbook in  which the code resides whereas `ActiveWorkbook` is the one that has the focus. They could be the same but must not be the same necessarily.

Don't bother with macro numbers. Instead, learn about arguments. A macro that does essentially one job, like your Macro_01 and Macro_02, can be combined into one macro with the 1 or 2 supplied as an argument.

The code below will help you on your way.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    ' 149
    
    Dim WsDisplay           As Worksheet
    Dim WsCalc              As Worksheet
    Dim Arg                 As String
    
    Set WsDisplay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set WsCalc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    If WsDisplay.Cells(3, "D").Value < 100 Then
        Arg = 1
    Else
        Arg = 2
    End If
'    ' Note: I would use the following in place of the above
'    '       because it's only a single line
'    Arg = 2 + (WbDisplay.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, "D").Value < 100)
    
    Action WsDisplay, Arg
End Sub

Private Sub Action(WsDisplay As Worksheet, _
                   ByVal Switch As Integer)
    ' 149

    Dim Target              As Range
    Dim Txt                 As String
    
    Select Case Switch
        Case 1
            Set Target = WsDisplay.Cells(3, 1)     ' 1 = column A
            Txt = "Hi"
        Case 2
            Set Target = WsDisplay.Cells(3, 2)     ' 2 = column B
            Txt = "Hello"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid switch"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    With Target
        .Value = Txt
        .Offset(1).Value = "there!"
    End With
End Sub
```

Look for the worksheet and workbook definitions in the `Main` procedure. The design is to let the CalcSheet be the active one but, later in the code, that sheet is never used. All the action is on the inactive DisplaySheet.

Comment: Hi, Your Answer Variatus helped me to improve the code to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: That's great to know. Thanks for the feedback. Please also mark the helpful answer as 'Selected'. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

Macro_01 and Macro_02 need to know which workbook they're operating on.

Eg:

```vb
Sub Macro_01()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DisplaySheet").Range("A3")
        .Value = "Hi_01"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        .Value = "There_01"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Your Answer Tim helped me to get it it to work. Thanks!